# Deployed my application successfully on Heroku but does not show other devices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, heroku

I deployed my application successfully on Heroku. It works fine for my laptop but it does not show on other devices. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**This is my database setup**

```
require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = require("./node_modules/sequelize");

const con = new sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialect: "postgres",
  protocol: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: true
  }
});

const Person = con.define("person", {
  image: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  firstname: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastname: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
});

const Post = con.define("post", {
  title: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  content: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  personid: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});

const Parent = con.define("parent", {
  father: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  mother: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  personid: { type: sequelize.INTEGER }
});

con.sync({ force: true });

module.exports = con;
```

**This is my Node js server setup.**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./schema");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

app.use(cors());

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    pretty: true,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
app.use(express.static("build"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", index.html));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`✅  Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
);
```

**This is my Procfile setup**

```
web: node server.js
```

After reading couple of articles, so far I understand its because of heroku cors settings. But I don't know how to enable cors setting on Heroku.

This is my heroku app link: `https://apask.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: It's not need any configuration cors in heroku. You only need to learn how to use cors in express.

Answer (score 0):

When your deploying on heroku it, you can add this to your server.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

const server = app.listen(PORT, HOST, function () {
  logger.info("Server running on: " + HOST + ":" + PORT)
  process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    server.close();
  });
});
```